# How to fix errors in header files in ruby 3.2.2 install

Tags: ruby, header-files

I'm trying to install `Ruby 3.2.2`. on an old **Macbook Pro (2014)** with **10.11.6** installed (I can't update to a more recent OS). This is the error I get with some system info. I also got the same error using `rbenv` ruby installer, and **unfortunately** Homebrew doesn't support my OS so there's no other way I've found to install.

This [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/9wrgr0Bh) shows the output of running `./configure` on official ruby download. I'm not sure if it's relevant to the error message I receive when running make.

Question: How can I work around these errors in the header files for a `3.2.2.` install?  (My current **Mac OS** only has **ruby 2** installed and basically all gems are unavailable to me)

```
    BASERUBY = echo executable host ruby is required.  use --with-baseruby option.; false
    CC = clang
    LD = clang
    LDSHARED = clang -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wundef   -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -fPIE -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin15 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/15.0.0 
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-pie -framework CoreFoundation  
    SOLIBS =  -ldl -lobjc -lpthread 
    LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = 
    MFLAGS = 
    RUSTC = no
    YJIT_RUSTC_ARGS = --crate-name=yjit --crate-type=staticlib --edition=2021 -g -C opt-level=3 -C overflow-checks=on '--out-dir=/Users/mm/Desktop/ruby-3.2.2/yjit/target/release/' ./yjit/src/lib.rs
clang version 5.0.0 (trunk 300079)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
compiling ./main.c


./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:392:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fmt'; did you mean 'fma'?
    RBIMPL_ATTR_DIAGNOSE_IF(rb_scan_args_count(fmt) <  0,    "bad scan arg format",                    "error")
                                               ^~~
                                               fma
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:230:57: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count'
#define rb_scan_args_count(fmt) rb_scan_args_count_lead(fmt, 0, 0)
                                                        ^
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:226:29: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_lead'
    (!rb_scan_args_isdigit((fmt)[ofs]) ? \
                            ^
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:195:63: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_isdigit'
#define rb_scan_args_isdigit(c) (RBIMPL_CAST((unsigned char)((c)-'0'))<10)
                                                              ^
./include/ruby/internal/cast.h:31:29: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_CAST'
# define RBIMPL_CAST(expr) (expr)
                            ^
./include/ruby/internal/attr/diagnose_if.h:35:36: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ATTR_DIAGNOSE_IF'
    __attribute__((__diagnose_if__(_, __, ___))) \
                                   ^
/usr/include/math.h:554:15: note: 'fma' declared here
extern double fma(double, double, double);
              ^
In file included from ./main.c:21:
In file included from ./include/ruby.h:38:
In file included from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:47:
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:392:29: error: subscript of pointer to function type
      'double (double, double, double)'
    RBIMPL_ATTR_DIAGNOSE_IF(rb_scan_args_count(fmt) <  0,    "bad scan arg format",                    "error")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:230:33: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count'
#define rb_scan_args_count(fmt) rb_scan_args_count_lead(fmt, 0, 0)
                                ^
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:226:28: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_lead'
    (!rb_scan_args_isdigit((fmt)[ofs]) ? \
                           ^
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:195:63: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_isdigit'
#define rb_scan_args_isdigit(c) (RBIMPL_CAST((unsigned char)((c)-'0'))<10)
                                                              ^
./include/ruby/internal/cast.h:31:29: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_CAST'
# define RBIMPL_CAST(expr) (expr)
                            ^
./include/ruby/internal/attr/diagnose_if.h:35:36: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ATTR_DIAGNOSE_IF'
    __attribute__((__diagnose_if__(_, __, ___))) \
                                   ^
In file included from ./main.c:21:
In file included from ./include/ruby.h:38:
In file included from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:47:
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:392:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fmt'; did you mean 'fma'?
    RBIMPL_ATTR_DIAGNOSE_IF(rb_scan_args_count(fmt) <  0,    "bad scan arg format",                    "error")
                                               ^~~
                                               fma
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:230:57: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count'
#define rb_scan_args_count(fmt) rb_scan_args_count_lead(fmt, 0, 0)
                                                        ^
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:227:29: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_lead'
     rb_scan_args_count_var(fmt, ofs, vari) : \
                            ^
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:216:7: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_var'
    ((fmt)[ofs]!='*' ? \
      ^
./include/ruby/internal/attr/diagnose_if.h:35:36: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ATTR_DIAGNOSE_IF'
    __attribute__((__diagnose_if__(_, __, ___))) \
                                   ^
/usr/include/math.h:554:15: note: 'fma' declared here
extern double fma(double, double, double);
              ^
In file included from ./main.c:21:
In file included from ./include/ruby.h:38:
In file included from ./include/ruby/ruby.h:47:
./include/ruby/internal/scan_args.h:392:29: error: subscript of pointer to function type
      'double (double, double, double)'
    RBIMPL_ATTR_DIAGNOSE_IF(rb_scan_args_count(fmt) <  0,    "bad scan arg format",                    "error")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Given your other question I guess you solved this? Could you self answer, it might help someone in the future?